# How do I write a code in such a way that gives me periodic cyclic curve?

Tags: java, python, logic

The context here is that I am trying to heat and cool an object, and I am trying to get cyclic temperature control system.

Assume Room temeprature =25 degrees celcius ( which is the temeprature of the object at the beginning). I want to build a curve seen on the image. The object should cool when it reaches 90 degrees after it has been heated to 90 degrees, when the object cools to 55 degrees, it should heat to 90 degrees celcius.

Image: [Cycling curve graph going from 50 to 90](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLKM2.png)

This is my code:

if ( temperature <= 55)

heat();

else if ( temperature >=90)

cool();

When the temperature value is 56 to 89, what happens?

My solution would be to put a heating function at the beginning, like heat () and then the if else statements.

Comment: Nothing happens when the temperature is 56 to 89. It depends how your `heat` and `cool` methods are defined. Maybe they gradually increase/decrease the temperature until that threshold.

Comment: @ZWiki, so how do i get that curves, it's so difficult. Are there any suggestions that you might give out.

Comment: Does it have to look similar to that with the sharp jumps/drops in temperature or should it be linear?

Comment: The curve has to look exactly like the picture.

Comment: What I would do it figure out what time you want to use. Allow `X` seconds/minutes/hours to be the amount of time you would like the temperature to go from A to B and then model a sin curve after that

Answer (score 0):

you really should make a better try at coding, but I was bored

this is a dynamic system simulation with linear 'heating/cooling' model and bang-bang controller

```
r_t =  1  # thermal resistance
t_cold = 0.8  # cooling temp
t_hot = 2.2   # heating temp
t_lo, t_hi = 1, 2  # controller thresholds
c_t = 100  # heat capacity

t_obj = [0]  # really cold start temp
h = []
for s in range(1000):
    if t_obj[-1] < t_lo:  # bang-bang logic
        heat = 1
    elif t_obj[-1] > t_hi:
        heat = 0

# equation integrating the the heat/cooling input to t_obj

    t_obj += [t_obj[-1] + ((heat * t_hot + (1 - heat) * t_cold) - t_obj[-1])/r_t/c_t]
    h.append(heat)

plt.plot(h)    # debug plot of `heat` state
plt.plot(t_obj)
```

[image]